# Unity: can't get Post-Processing Stack v2 effects to work with LWRP

Tags: unity-game-engine, stack, render, lwrp

I'm trying to set up some post processing effects for my scene in Unity 2019.1.1.
I'm currently using LWRP v5.7.2 and Post Processing v2.1.7

I created a PostProcessing Profile and I attached a Post Processing Layer and Post Processing Volume to my MainCamera.

When I set some effects on the PP Volume or in the PP Profile I see no difference in my view: no effect is actually applied.

Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: What Layer is your Post Processing setup for.  I see it is Mixed.  Typically what is done is to create a new PostProcessing layer and assign it to the "Post Processing Layer" script.  That way, post processing is sped up since it will only check those layers.  Basically, what layers have you applied to the "Post Processing Layer Script"?

Comment: I added all the layer of the objects in my scene (Environment, Player, and so on..) 
I didn't leave "Everything" because a popup warning suggests to avoid it.